# How to access assoc array within assoc array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
def operation hash
  puts hash[:three][:three][:three]
end

operation :one => 'item', :two => [1,2,3], :three => [
    :one => 1,
    :two => 2,
    :three => [
        :one => 1,
        :two => 2,
        :three => [
            :test1,
            :test2
        ]
    ]
]
```

I would like to access the item hash[:three][:three][:three] to output [test1, test2].
Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

A `Hash` needs to be surrounded by braces `{}`, not brackets `[]`, which are reserved for arrays.

Unlike PHP, in Ruby these are distinct types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 def operation hash
  puts hash[:three][0][:three][0][:three]  #=> [:test1, :test2]
end
```

Notice that each of the `:three` keys has an array storing the values.

Comment: Actually no. Each of the arrays contains only 1 element, hence the index 0.